# Decryption of Huffman code

Tags: compression

I know that Huffman is not a encryption method, but I have a bit-stream that I know it's Huffman coded. However, the tree/table that maps the codes to real characters is not available. Surprisingly, during my searches I couldn't find helpful sources or even academic papers on this problem. It seems this problem has no literature.

Can anyone introduce a helpful resource on this? Is there any algorithm that I can devise or adapt to solve this problem?

P.S. Actually I know that the bit-stream is a JPEG file which is Huffman coded.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/wauy-kbEGN4) and a paper from 1996 [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/GMR96.pdf). I had looked at this cursorily years ago, it is not so easy. And a google search brings up some other papers. The discussion may be the way to start.